# How to get woocommerce orders by product ID wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get all orders in woocommerce filtered by product id
Ex. if I want to know how many orders placed of product XYZ where product ID is 123.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fetch results using following query:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 
   'SELECT wpp.order_item_id as OrderPrimaryID,wpp.order_id as OrderID,
           wpm.meta_value as OrderProductId,wpsot.post_author as OrderPostAuthor,
           wpu.ID as OrderUserID,wpu.user_email as OrderUserEmail FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items as wpp 
    INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as wpm ON wpp.order_item_id=wpm.order_item_id 
    INNER JOIN wp_posts wpsot ON wpp.order_id=wpsot.ID 
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wppostmeta ON wpp.order_id=wppostmeta.post_id 
    INNER JOIN wp_users wpu ON wppostmeta.meta_value=wpu.ID 
    WHERE wpm.meta_key="_product_id" AND wppostmeta.meta_key="_customer_user"', 
    OBJECT 
);
print_r($results);
```

Hope it helps.